# php, POST, textarea is always empty

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id_article=\"$editid\"";
            $edited = $db->query($query)->fetch_object();
            echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\" id=\"add_article\" >";
            echo "ID menu <select name=\"urlmenu\" form=\"add_article\">";

            $query = "SELECT id_menuitem,url,name FROM menu_item";
            $result =$db->query($query);
            while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {

                echo "<option value=\"$obj->id_menuitem\">$obj->name</option>";
            }

            echo "</select></br>";
            echo "Name <input type=text name=name value='$edited->name'></br>";
            echo "Perex <input type=text name=perex value='$edited->perex'></br>";
            echo "Keywords <input type=text name=keywords value='$edited->keywords'></br>";
            echo "<textarea name=content cols=100 rows=20>$edited->content</textarea><br>";
            echo '<input type=submit value=Edit name=editstate>';
            echo "<input type=hidden value=$editid name=id>";
            echo '</form>';

if (isset($_POST["editstate"]))
        {
            $b = false;
            $perex = addslashes($_POST["perex"]);
            $content = addslashes($_POST["content"]);
            $name = addslashes($_POST["name"]);
            $id = addslashes($_POST["id"]);
            echo var_dump($_POST);
            $query = "UPDATE articles SET perex=\"$perex\", content=\"$content\", name=\"$name\" WHERE id_article = $id";
            $db->query($query);
        }
```

I want to send form data via post method, everything works except the textarea.
**`vardump`** always shows that its empty

```
array(7) { ["urlmenu"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(4) "Abcd" ["perex"]=> string(4) "Dfeg" ["keywords"]=> string(4) "Hjkl" ["editstate"]=> string(4) 
"Edit" ["id"]=> string(1) "5" **["content"]=> string(0)** "" }
```

i also tried to add `"form"` attribute to the textarea but the result is always same

Comment: show us your form (html-code)

Comment: Use `echo "<textarea name=content cols=100 rows=20>'$edited->content'</textarea><br>";`

Comment: Please check `$edited->content` have data or not . normally if i do like this:-  http://prntscr.com/7anv5x then after submitting i get this:- http://prntscr.com/7anvgf. I am getting the value what i putted in textarea after submission. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a stupid mistake, I had two forms with same id.

Comment: hint: in futer seperate html from php ... it's no good practice the way you go. hint 2 (in html) put attributes in quots eg <textarea name="foo" id="bar" ...